# How to center a TableRow programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am creating a number of buttons in a table row programmatically, but they always end up left-aligned. How can I center the entire row? I am trying this to create each row:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
row.setLayoutParams(params);

for (int j = 0; j != numButtonCols; j++) {
    Button b = new Button(getActivity());
    b.setOnClickListener(actionListener);
    row.addView(b);
    actionButtons[j][i] = b;
}

layout.addView(row);
```

Comment: I guess `row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);` didn't help?

Comment: Thanks, setGravity() was the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply center the row using a [`Gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html). Just set it to your row with

```
row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
    TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    row.setLayoutParams(params);

    TableRow.LayoutParams buttonParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    for (int j = 0; j != numButtonCols; j++) {
        Button b = new Button(getActivity());
        b.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
        b.setOnClickListener(actionListener);
        row.addView(b);
        actionButtons[j][i] = b;
    }

layout.addView(row);
```